# Initialising a matrix of zeros using an existing function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I have this code:

```
def initialise(m, n, value):
    if not m <= 0:
        stop_program(f'{m} is not a valid number of lines')
    if not n <= 0:
        stop_program(f'{n} is not a valid number of columns)
    if not is_number(value):
        stop_program(f'{value} is not a valid number')
    return [[value for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
```

whereas is_number is a function that verifies if the value entered is a number and where stop_program is a function that stops the programming if the value entered isn't a valid number. The last code creates a matrix mxn that only contains the number 'value'.

Now using the function initialise, I have to create a matrix of zeros but i don't know how. So far i tried using a for condition but I don't know what to add in that condition to create a row of zeros and columns of zeros:

```
def zeros(m, n):
    for init(m):
        #condition and create a column of zeros
    for init(n):
        #condition and create a line of zeros
return []
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Did you mean: `def zeros(m, n): return initialise(m, n, 0)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a matrix of zeros as follows:

`zero_matrix = [[0]*m]*n`

where `m` are the number of columns and `n` the number of rows. Or, you can use the zeros function from numpy

```
from numpy import zeros

zero_matrix = zeros(n,m)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please not that the `for` keyword is looping over the elements, if you want to check a conditions use the `if` `else` statement.

There are several ways of creating an array of zeros:

Using loops:

```
row = []
for _ in range(10):
   row.append(0)

# output
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

```
col = []
for _ in range(10):
    col.append([0])

# output 
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
```

As a list comprehension:

```
row = [0 for _ in range(10)]

# output
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Or by using other packages, such as [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

```
import numpy as np 
matrix = np.zeros((3, 2))

# Output
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), your `zeros` function could look like this:

```
def zeros(m, n, value=0):
    return [[[0] for _ in range(m)] for _ in range(n)]
zeros(3, 3, 0)
```

Out:

```
[[[0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

just:

```
def zeros(m, n):
    return initialize(m, n, 0)
```

#### Remarks:

- If you don't want re-implement matrix manipulation yourself I suggest you look at [numpy](https://numpy.org/) package. You can use it to do something like `zeors_matrix = np.zeros((2, 3))` to have a 2x3 zero matrix.
- `return []` will always return an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The most traditional way is with numpy:

```
def initialise(m, n, value):
    if not m <= 0:
        stop_program(f'{m} is not a valid number of lines')
    if not n <= 0:
        stop_program(f'{n} is not a valid number of columns)
    if not is_number(value):
        stop_program(f'{value} is not a valid number')
    return np.zeros(m, n)
```

If you only want to use  in-built funtionality:

```
def initialise(m, n, value):
    if m <= 0:
            stop_program(f'{m} is not a valid number of lines')
    elif n <= 0:
            stop_program(f'{n} is not a valid number of columns)
    elif not is_number(value):
        stop_program(f'{value} is not a valid number')
    else:
        zero_mat = []
        for i in range(m):
            zero_row = []
            for _ in range(n):
                zero_row.append(value)
            zero_mat.append(zero_row)
        return zero_mat
```

Here, if you input zero as value, you would get intended result. Bur you also can use any other value, which seem to be you real intention.